# GODOT animation player

Tags: animation, game-development, godot, gdscript

I'm making a personal project for school, but I seem to be having a problem which is the following, I used an RPG Godot template, the problem is that for the title screen I want to implement animation for the title, but I can't, I don't know why or how to do it, help, please???

Comment: Are you talking about this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66fD0Pl2UP4 ?

Comment: Well, regardless, I suppose I should point you towards [`AnimationPlayer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_animationplayer.html) or [`AnimatedSprite`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_animatedsprite.html), or [`VideoPlayer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_videoplayer.html) even. You might also be interested in [Background loading](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/io/background_loading.html) (you know, in case you can take advantage of the animation time to load assets).

Comment: @Theraot Yes that's exactly the template I'm using, but I want to add n animation for the title screen, but I don't know how to add it to the title screen, I already made the animation, my problem is I don't know how to add it to the title screen and make it play when it gets there...

Comment: 1. When you way title screen, you mean where it says "GemeTitle" (i.e. the Menu scene)? 2. How and where you made the animation?

Comment: @Theraot, yup that's exactly what I mean, more specifically I made the animation in Menu.tscn as a child of that scene, and I used the game title sprite. To make the animation I used an AnimationPlayer and well did the animation using the tools the engine provides. And btw thanks for taking the time to help me, I'm new to game dev and to Godot so really thanks a lot really appreciate it :D

Answer (score 2):

If you have an animation in an `AnimationPlayer` and you want it to play as soon as the scene loads, you can set the animation to Autoplay on load.

With the `AnimationPlayer` selected, in the Animation panel (bottom of the window), select the animation form the drop down list, and click the "Autoplay on load" button just right from said drop down list. It looks like `|A>`.

Here, picture:

[image: "Autoplay on load" button]